# Arduino Ultrasonic Sensor AnalogRead

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, ultrasonics

i have an ultrasonic sensor. The sensor normally works stably. But I have to carry the data cables of this sensor for 50 meters and take reading. When i do this, when I extend the cable, the values I get from the sensor are not read stably.

I need to raise the sensor voltage so I can fix this problem, how can you help me?

Comment: Can you put another Arduino next to the Ultrasonic Sensor and connect them both over WiFi/BT or a radio module?

Comment: you'll need an interconnection designed to span such distances, like ethernet, wifi,  rs485, etc.

Comment: I take a value between 0-5 Volts according to the distance. I want to increase these values from 0-5 Volts linearly to 10-15 Volts. How can I do that?

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem: increasing the voltage will not "fix" the problem, it will only slightly improve performance. But only if you **amplify** the signal. Shifting 0-5V to 10-15V will do nothing! You just shouldn't transmit an analog voltage over such a long distance. You'd better transmit a 4-20mA signal or even better choose a suitable digital interface

Comment: All ultrasonic distance sensors, that I have seen so far, don't output an analog voltage. What sensor do you have?

Comment: What kind of sensor ? Pulse output ? Serial output ? Only extend data cables ?